# How can you link an Android Developer Notification Purchase with a User ID?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

We've implemented Android Developer Realtime Notifications in our app and they've been working great. I was wondering if there is any way to link the notification with a user from our app. Many times the connection was lost and the APP couldn't tell our API that there was a successful purchase; we then receive that purchase through the notifications, but I don't know which user to assign it to. Is there any way to do this or is there a best practice?